# what does it mean by namespace Win has no member "simpleControl"

Tags: c++, winapi

Trying to understand win api programming but i have ran to an issue. In vs 2017 i can not get rid of the error namespace win has no member 'simpleControl'. I have search the net for an answer but could not find one to my particular problem. I am hoping someone can shed some light on my problem. Do i have cyclical dependencies problem if so how can i solve my issue i have some code in case any one wants to help me

```
#pragma once
#ifndef WIN_SIMPLE_CONTROL_H
#define WIN_SIMPLE_CONTROL_H

#include "Controller.h"

namespace Win
{
    class simpleControl: public Controller
    {
    public:
        simpleControl();
        ~simpleControl() {};

        int close();                                
        int command(int id, int cmd, LPARAM msg);   
        int create();                               

     private:

    };
   }

#endif
```

My simpleControl inherits from controller.h class which also is a namespace of Win how can i have simpleControl also in the Win namespace my main function is as follows

```
 #include <windows.h>
 #include "Window.h"
 #include "controller.h"

 int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInst, HINSTANCE hPrevInst, LPSTR cmdArgs, int 
 cmdShow)
 {
    MSG   Msg;
    char name[] = "Simple Window";
    Win::simpleControl mainCtrl; ->>>>///my problem is here 
    Win::Window mainWin(hInst, name, 0, &mainCtrl);

    mainWin.create();
    mainWin.show();

    /// Process the main window's messages
    while( GetMessage(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0) )
    {
        TranslateMessage(&Msg);
        DispatchMessage(&Msg);
    }

    return 0;
   }
```

my header file for controller is as follows

```
 #pragma once

 #ifndef WIN_CONTROLLER_H
 #define WIN_CONTROLLER_H

 #include <Windows.h>

 namespace Win
 {
    class Controller
    {
      public:
        Controller();
        virtual ~Controller();

        //window handle
        void setHandle(HWND handle);

        //WM_CLOSE
        virtual int close();

        virtual int command(int id, int cmd, LPARAM msg);
        virtual int create();
        virtual int destroy();

        protected:
        HWND handle;
    };

    inline void Controller::setHandle(HWND hwnd) { handle = hwnd; }
    inline int Controller::close() { ::DestroyWindow(handle); 
    return 0;
    }
    inline int Controller::command(int id, int cmd, LPARAM msg) {
    return 0;
    }
     inline int Controller::create() { return 0; }
     inline int Controller::destroy() { return 0; }


   }

   #endif
```

Comment: Did you include the file that defines `simpleControl`? Hard to tell if your include guards don't match the filename. We also can't tell if you have cyclical dependencies because you did not show what's in controller.h. You may want to read [mcve].

Comment: `simpleControl` != `simpelControl`.

Comment: sorry about that i miss spelled simpleControl but i still have the same problem

Comment: So Controller is stored in "Controller.h" and simpleControl is stored in "controller.h" ?  Why else would one have a capital C and the other a lower case c?  Can you edit the question to show what the names of each file is?

Comment: What about `#include "Window.h"`?

Comment: It's unclear, what you are doing. Please show a [mcve]. Make sure you understand, that it needs to be *minimal*, so you don't need a Windows GUI application, no window creation, no message loop, no real class members.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should include a header file and namespace that defines simpleControl. 
Thanks! Also, you shall share Window.h with us.

Comment: Clearly, *Controller.h* does **not** define the class `simpleControl`. After all, the header file that defines `simpleControl` does contain an `#include "Controller.h"` directive.

Comment: I am taking about controller.h not Controller.h. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: This is Windows. The filesystem API is case insensitive, and C++ compilers on Windows follow suit. *Controller.h*, *controller.h*, and *CoNtRoLlEr.H* designate the same file.